# How can I skip the next Variable that is inserted In the same line?

Tags: java, algorithm

I put 1, 2, 3 then I want only 1 and 3 to be view.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("medicine.txt"));
while(line= br.readLine() != null) {

    System.out.print("line+"br.readLine()):
}
```

Comment: have you tried to split the line and only get the elements you want ?

Comment: ok. and what exactly is stopping you?

Comment: It's the array the output should always be together because we are using crud as database I'll need to view the important details only

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should split your line with the character ','

```
while(line = br.readLine() != null) {
    String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");
    System.out.println(splittedLine[0] + "-" + splittedLine[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a myriad of ways but if you always want to skip "2", something like this should work:

```
while(line = br.readLine() != null) {
    if (line.equals("2")) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.print("line: " + line);
}
```

Comment: "the next variable", so it's dependent on the location in the String, not it's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use counter and check if counter reached your line.

Comment: little vague for an answer

Comment: It's like the student data where u add all info's  like I'd, name, age, year, sec, height, weight, nationality, parents.  But the output you only need to view is name, age, year and sec